# Conexión con base de datos remota con DBeaver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

Estoy queriendo conectarme a una base de datos remota mediante una ip con el programa DBeaver pero no sé como. Podrían ayudarme con una simple guía, por último estoy en el sistema operativo linux Ubuntu 18.04. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: eso no deberia estar en el manual del programa?

Comment: No encontré nada al respecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La conexion es simple, sigue estos pasos:

1.- Verifica que tienes conexion al servidor remoto.

2.- Identifica el tipo de base de datos a la cual te debes conectar ya que en DBeaver debes utilizar el driver especifico. Por ejemplo Mysql, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, etc

3.- En la pantalla principal del gestor de base de datos presiona el boton para crear una nueva conexion.

4.- En la proxima pantalla selecciona el driver, supongamos que te conectas a MySQL. Tambien debes completar los campos de Server Host / IP, Puerto, Database, User name, Password.

5.- En la proxima pantalla coloca un nombre cualquiera a la conexion, elige el tipo de conexion que desees, luego le das al boton finalizar y ya deberias tener conexion.

Adjunto un link que te puede ayudar como guia.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-mysql-database-with-dbeaver/